# Drupal 7 Syntax Highlighter not applied when logged in as user or admin

Tags: users, input-formats

I have a Drupal 7 website.

I installed the syntax highlighter module and downloaded the library.
I was very careful following instructions when configuring the module. I also configured it to get the "insert syntax highlighter button" when using the ckeditor library through the wysiwyg module. Yet, the highlighting is only applied when I preview an article.

If I do save that article, the highlighting is gone. Then if I logout, it is applied as an anonymout user. So my question is... Is this normal? I've been trying to fix this for hours but no luck.

Comment: It seams some JavaScript applied when you are logged in. check your browsers console for errors...

Comment: it is partially applied I should say. The font and the indentation is there but that's it.

Comment: I checked the console as you suggested but no luck. Here are the console errors:
[09:30:09.166] Error: Permission denied to access property 'toString'
--
[09:30:36.614] TypeError: $.cookie is not a function @ http://crownlessking.com/modules/toolbar/toolbar.js?meto1e:29
[09:30:40.518] Error: Permission denied to access property 'toString'

Answer (score 0):

Well, since nobody seems to want to answer my question, I will provide my solution to the problem. As I have discovered. Drupal do not load all javascripts, go figure why.

So, what I did is go to the admin panel. In configuration/performance you can aggregate all javascript files into one big file which apparently helps minimize server requests. When I did that, it worked. The syntax highlighting is now applied all the time, with a nasty side effect.

I got my code-hightlighting effect working but now, the wysiwyg shows up in comment's textarea field with a background that matches my websites... How unfortunate!